# Tornado handler that forks additional work in python

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x, tornado

I have a simple API exposed via tornado. Previously, one of the queries caused an `rsync` to run. Through trial, error, exploration, I found that I could fork that off so that it didn't block a timely response:

```
tornado.process.Subprocess(['rsync', '-vazh', ... ])
```

I'm evolving this code now so that it no longer runs an external `rsync`, but instead pokes another service. I'm using Requests to do so:

```
requests.post('http://other.service/foo/bar)
```

The network behind this service has really high latencies (same for the rysnc process), so I'd still like that to be forked off so that I don't put off a timely response. The `tornado.process.Subprocess` seems well suited for calling non python shell programs to get work done. Is there an equivalent for doing so for python code like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tornado` has a built-in HTTP client that you can use in place of `requests`: [`tornado.httpclient`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html)

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://other.service/foo/bar", method='POST', callback=handle_request)
```

It can also be used as a coroutine, if you want:

```
@coroutine
def some_method(self):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    repsonse = yield http_client.fetch("http://other.service/foo/bar", method='POST')
   if response.error:
       print "Error:", response.error
   else:
       print response.body
```

If you're running arbitrary blocking Python code (meaning something that you can't easily find a non-blocking, tornado-compatible replacement for), you should probably consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15375336/2073595), about using multiprocessing with `tornado`. The short answer is that on Python 3.x you'd probably want to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to run the blocking code, since `concurrent.futures.Future` will integrate properly with the `tornado` event loop when you `yield` from one.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Only thing I had to tweak, was adding a `body` parameter. That's apparently required when `method = 'POST'`. Maybe update example?