# Split a long process to multiple processes in Tornado framework

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, tornado

I have a very long process which takes around 300 seconds to complete. I am using socket programming in tornado framework to do this. Now I am trying to improve the speed using the multiprocessing.

For this, I changed my app.py to something like this.

```
global http_server
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)

# Commented the previous code.
# http_server.listen(port)
# signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)
# signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
# tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

http_server.bind(port)
http_server.start(0)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now, In one of the request handlers, I wrote the below code and it is giving an error. However, the same code had worked when I tried it as a core python script without Tornado.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4)
m = 10000000
print "map with multiproc: "
t = time.time()
r = pool.map(my_func, range(m))
```

The error says

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup thread.lock failed

How to fix this?

Comment: May I see `my_func`, especially how it return value.

Comment: Are you using any method from the `threading` library? Did you have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32274262/4121573